# Moment-Timezone: Retrieve DST start and end times

Tags: javascript, momentjs, dst

Does moment-timezone support (or has anyone been able to implement) retrieving the start/end times for Daylight Savings Time for a given zone? I'm not looking to determine if a given date/time in a zone is within DST, but rather the actual transition times for the zone.

This doesn't seem to be supported, but thought maybe someone had been able to accomplish this.

Comment: Daylight savings gets applied the first Sunday of March and rescinded the second Sunday of November; see: http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/daylight_time.php

Comment: Thanks for the link - timezones worldwide don't follow the same transition scheme, though, so I'm looking to see if anyone has pulled this information from moment-timezone. I'm currently trying to move to exclusive use of moment-timezone, but one of the features of a python library I've used for a long time, pytz, supplies DST start and end.

Comment: I think that http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/ is what you are looking for.  It seems to give all the offset and related timestamps as well as abbreviations.  Have a look too to http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-formats/ which helps making sense of the data.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @tgo - brillant, thanks, don't know how I missed that. I can map Zone.untils (in seconds from epoch) to Zone.offsets and get exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem.